# Ember.js: How do you load model into addon hbs template?

Tags: ember.js

Maybe I just don't know the correct terminology or something but I can't figure out how to do this. Ember is pretty new to me, and it's pretty lacking in documentation it seems.

I am using the ember background video plugin. I've got that working perfectly.

```
{{#background-video
  muted
  mp4="../assets/video-bg.mp4"
  poster="../assets/Main-bg.jpg"
}}
{{/background-video}}
```

I've setup a model to iterate through background videos loaded through the CMS (Drupal 8). I've also got this working exactly like I want. It displays the URL to the video:

```
{{video-bg video=model.video_bg}}
```

How do you get the model to display inside the addon script?

Like this:

```
{{#background-video
  muted
  mp4="{{video-bg video=model.video_bg}}"
  poster="../assets/Main-bg.jpg"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `video-bg` is a helper you can use it as [subexpression](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/templates/built-in-helpers/#toc_nesting-built-in-helpers):

```
{{#background-video
  muted
  mp4=(video-bg video=model.video_bg)
  poster="../assets/Main-bg.jpg"
}}
```

However this will not work if `video-bg` is a component. Then there is no way to do this in the template layer, and you need to refactor to either `video-bg` being a helper, or probably better, being a computed property.